# Как записать значение в атрибут элемента?

Tags: javascript

Необходимо, чтобы значение атрибута "номер" выбранного элемента списка записывалось в атрибут "текущий номер" блочного элемента div. Подскажите плиз!

```
<html>
  <head>Вывод содержимого элемента списка</head>
  <body>
    <div текущий номер=""> 
      <ul>
        <li номер="1">Первый</li>
        <li номер="2">Второй</li>
      </ul>
    </div> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var li_elements = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
        for (i = 0; i < li_elements.length; i++) {
          li_elements[i].onclick = function () {
            alert("номер элемента: " + this.getAttribute("номер"));
            document.body.div.setAttribute('текущий номер', 'this.getAttribute("номер")');
            }
          }
      </script>
  </body>   
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
el.setAttribute("номер", "1")
```

Answer (score 1):

Наименование аттрибута не может содержать пробел. Ваш пример будет выглядеть так

```
<html> 
  <head>Вывод содержимого элемента списка</head> 
  <body> 
    <div текущийномер="">  
      <ul> 
        <li номер="1">Первый</li> 
        <li номер="2">Второй</li> 
      </ul> 
    </div>  
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var lielements = document.getElementsByTagName('li'); 
        for (i = 0; i < lielements.length; i++) { 
          lielements[i].onclick = function () { 
            alert("номер элемента: " + this.getAttribute("номер")); 
            document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].текущийномер=this.номер; 
            alert(document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].текущийномер)
            } 
          } 
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: почему-то значение атрибута "номер" все равно не сохраняется в атрибуте текущий_номер элемента div!

Comment: в IE работает, а Firefox не позволяет добавить произвольный атрибут.
Замените "текущийномер" на "title" или другой текстовый атрибут и всё будет хорошо.

Comment: если title не подходит попробуйте атрибут id